# Maven stopped loading dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am using Maven in my Spring Tool Suite. 
After some time the imports of the spring library could not be resolved anymore.

[image]

> The import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate cannot be
>   resolved

I think maven causes the problem. But I do not know why. 
All the other imports are still working.

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>DatabaseProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>DatabaseProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: mvn clean install works or fails ?

Comment: Can you try a Project -> Clean and see if that fixes it?

Comment: If this is Eclipse, "Maven->Update Project" sometimes helps .

Comment: @Berger Maven->Update Project did the trick

Comment: Nice, it often fixes things for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be related to the configuration of maven.

If you are working in a company that introduced a proxy, maven is not able to exit if not correctly configured.

If a dependency was previously downloaded there is no problem because maven takes the local version of the dependency, but if you try to use a new dependency you can't see the new jars in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked for me:

```
   Right Click on Project -> Maven -> Update Project
```

Answer (score 0):

In STS Project explorer, select the project and press `Alt+F5` to update maven